# Fetching the value of a variable from server side (nodejs / express) in client side JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the petfinder API and while I'm doing the authentication on the server side, I need to access the token generated in my client side JS.

In my server.js file I have the following:

```js
require('dotenv').config({ path: './config/.env' });

const petfinder = require('@petfinder/petfinder-js');

const petKeys = process.env.PET_KEY;
const petSecret = process.env.PET_SECRET;

let client = new petfinder.Client({
    apiKey: petKeys,
    secret: petSecret,
});

client.authenticate().then(resp => {
    tokenInfo = {
        token: resp.data.access_token,
        expires: resp.data.expires_in,
        tokenType: resp.data.token_type,
    };
});
```

How can I access that tokenInfo object on the client side JS file?

Comment: That's not a good idea. If you allow the client to get the token, the user can get it and access your petfinder account.

Comment: But if you really need to do it, add a route in your server that returns the token, and use AJAX in the client to call it.